# Matching timestamps and calculating time differences (R)

Tags: r, merge, timestamp

I have a DF containing time stamps and the type of corresponding "event" (two types of events), and another one with the timestamps and types of event **acknowledgements**.

I'm trying to claculate the time between an event, and the time at which it is acknowledged.

Acknowledgements can be received immediately, or later (`Tack>=Tevent`) or never. If there is no corresponding acknowledgement, I'd like the time difference to show `NA`

Example:

```
dfEvent
Time      Event
00:00:01     A
00:01:00     B
00:05:00     A
00:09:00     B

dfAcknowledgement
Time      Event
00:00:02     A
00:05:10     A
00:09:05     B

RESULT
Time      Event   Delay
00:00:01     A    00:00:01
00:01:00     B    NA
00:05:00     A    00:00:10
00:09:00     B    00:00:05
```

- I've been looking at `data.table` but I don't just want to merge tables: I want to calculate the difference between the values of two "nearby" rows
- I was also thinking of using `which()` to find the index of the event corresponding to an acknowledgement, but once I've got the index, how do I subtract it from the corresponding row without a for loop ?

Comment: But then couldn't there be situations where you have two A events but the acknowledgment for the second arrives before the first? This isn't a very clear matching algorithm. Is there a maximum difference you would tolerate?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention this: there can not be two similar events in a row: only A-B-A-B-A, there would never be any A-A-A-B. And  if the acknolwedgement is not received before the next event, it has been discarded and will never be received.

Comment: And you'll never have consecutive discarded A AND B events? One of the two will always be acknowledged?

Comment: If the system switches from A too B to fast, Acknowledgements don't have time to arrive before the next change of state, and are discarded.So multiple consecutive acknoledgements could be lost. However, any acknoledgement received will always relate to the event (of the same type) which occured immediately before the acknowledgement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define inputs `dfEvent` and `dfAcknowledgement` and then convert to data.table with appropriate keys also computing `NextTime`.  Then perform a rolling join of the data.tables, resort by `Time` and keep only `Time`, `Event` and computed `Delay`.

```
library(data.table)
library(chron)

# test data from question
dfEvent <- data.frame(Time = c("00:00:01", "00:01:00", "00:05:00", "00:09:00"),
 Event = c("A", "B"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dfAcknowledgement <- data.frame(Time = c("00:00:02", "00:05:10", "00:09:05"),
 Event = c("A", "A", "B"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# convert to data.table (also compute NextTime column)
dtEvent <- with(dfEvent, data.table(Event = Event, Time = times(Time), 
                            NextTime = times(c(tail(Time, -1), NA)),
                            key = "Event,Time"))
dtAcknowledgement <- with(dfAcknowledgement, data.table(Event = Event, 
                            Time = times(Time), TimeAck = times(Time),
                            key = "Event,Time"))


# real work done here - perform rolling join, re-sort & compute desired columns
roll <- dtAcknowledgement[dtEvent,,roll=-Inf]
setkey(setkey(roll, NULL), Time, Event)
roll[, list(Time, Event, Delay = replace(TimeAck, TimeAck>=NextTime, NA)-Time)]
```

This gives:

```
       Time Event    Delay
1: 00:00:01     A 00:00:01
2: 00:01:00     B     <NA>
3: 00:05:00     A 00:00:10
4: 00:09:00     B 00:00:05
```

Comment: Brilliant! Another use of the great data.table package I didn't know of. Thank you.